# nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 19 Connection has no connected handler

Tags: ios

The console of Xcode continue print

> **__nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 6 Connection has no connected handler**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I just found the answer.

From `Xcode` menu open: `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme`

Add `Environment` Variables `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` = `disable`

Comment: This only hides the error logs, the memory leak does not go away.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. This only hides the error logs in the console. that's all.